# how to make every point display multiple data on every point with highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need your help , how to display multiple data per point with basic line highchart ?

for example look at this image 
[image]

look that this chart is a basic line highchart wich show just x: 15 it did not show any other info

but my team leader asked me  to make the basic line highchart the same as the following image

[image]

that is easy , but my problem is how to make every point shows multiple data the same as  my team leader image  which displays the spent , the views , the clicks and the shares of every post but my chart just able to  display one of them.

thanks every body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a tooltip formatter function in plotOptions.tooltip.formatter. see this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter